# Let $S$ be the smallest positive multiple of $15$, that comprises exactly $3k$ digits with $k$ $0$'s, $k$ $3$'s and $k$ $8$'s.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

The following is taken from Singapore Mathematical Olympiad $2013$ Junior Round $1$.

Let $S$ be the smallest positive multiple of $15$, that comprises exactly $3k$ digits with $k$ $0$'s, $k$ $3$'s and $k$ $8$'s. Find the remainder when $S$ is divided by $11$.

I know that $S$ must end with digit $0$ since it is a multiple of $15$. From here I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline**

You are right. It must end in $0$ for it to be divisible by $5$. For it to be divisible by $3$, it has to have three $8$'s. Which means the minimum **k = 3** at which point the smallest number is $\color{blue}{300338880}$ which leaves a remainder $\color{blue}{6}$ when divided by $11$

Comment: Can explain why divisible by $3$ has to have three $8$'s? In general, can I say that any number divisible by $3$ must contains $3k$ $8$'s?

Comment: @Idonknow See, any number consisting of arbitrary numbers of $0$'s and $3$'s is always divisible by $3$ (Sum of digits). When you introduce $8$s we want the sum of digits to be still divisible. One $8$ will not work, neither $2$. But three $8$'s will make the number divisible again. You are not right on any number.  e.g. $18$ has only one $8$.  But here $1$ helped. If you have $0$s and $3$s only, then $8$ itself is the only help. So you need $3k$ of them. If there is any more explanation needed, pls ask.

Comment: So am I right to say that $N$ is divisible by a prime $p$ if and only if sum of digits of $N$ is divisible by $p$?

Comment: @Idonknow  No.  Not true for any prime. See divisibility tests for 3 and 9. (Counter example for you is 49 is divisible by 7)

Comment: Thanks. In the solution provided, after obtaining $S=300338880$, then we have $0-8+8-8+3-3+0-0+3 \equiv 6 ($ mod $11$ ). Why the last congruence valid?

Comment: @Idonknow  That is the test for divisibility for 11. See [explanation](http://mathforum.org/k12/mathtips/ward.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35773/discussion-between-shailesh-and-idonknow).

Comment: The rule of divisibility by 3 iff 3 divides the sum of the digits, is expected to be known by everyone.  The test for divisibility by 11 is the the odd digits minus the even digits will be 0 or a multiple of 11.

Comment: @fleablood I agree but OP did not seem to know

Answer (score 0):

We need the smallest available number.  We can't use an initial 0 so we start with a 3.  Then come k-1 0's, saving the last zero for the units digit.  Then the remaining k-1 3's, then the 8's and finally the last 0.

Split the number into 2-digit groups starting from the units digit and add these groups together.  This sum is less than the original number by a multiple of 99 and so has the same remainder upon dividing by 11.

The sum will contain some 33's and 88's.  These can be dropped because they contribute zero remainders when divided by 11.  When k is odd the remaining nonzero terms are 80+3 giving a remainder of 6, when k is even we end up with 80+38+30 which leaves a remainder of 5.